# Implementing a feedparser client for the bud framework in golang

Tags: go, web-applications

I am trying over the Bud full-stack framework and I wanted to implement a simple RSS parser to get data at each request.

I have been following pretty closely the tutorial made by Bud's creator, Matt Mueller https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoypcRqn-xA&t=601s and then I modified some of the code of the client he uses in the video to get hackernews json. I just want to be able to call for the data  at each request and print it to the screen. However, While it compiles, I encounter an error at runtime

```
conjure: generate "bud/.app/controller/controller.go" > controller: unable to load definition for field Extensions in sto
ries > parser: unable to find declaration for "Extensions" in "ext"
|
```

I have tried using feed instead of stories as an object name, creating a struct with a pointer to gofeed.Feed but nothing worked. I hypothize this has something to do with the way I use gofeed parser but it seems I can't manage to find the issue. Do you have any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

This is my client.go file

```golang
// Package feedparser is a simple RSS reader client that leverages gofeed
package feedparser

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/mmcdole/gofeed"
)


const baseURL = `https://ec.europa.eu/info/news/feed_en`

// Feed Client, it uses gofeed parser to open a connection with the rss/atom/json data feed
func New() *Client {
    feedParser := gofeed.NewParser()
    return &Client{feedParser}
}

// Feed Client
type Client struct {
    *gofeed.Parser
}


// FrontPage gets the feeds and prints them as a list
func (c *Client) FrontPage(ctx context.Context) (*gofeed.Feed, error) {

    feedData := `<rss version="2.0">
                            <channel>
                            <webMaster>example@site.com (Example Name)</webMaster>
                            </channel>
                            </rss>`

    fd, err := c.RSSTranslator.Translate(feedData)
    if err != nil {
        return fd, err
    }
    fmt.Println(fd)
    return fd, nil
}
```

This is my controller.go file

```golang
package controller

import (
    context "context"

    "github.com/AlessioNar/eunews/feedparser"
    "github.com/mmcdole/gofeed"
)

type Controller struct {
    // Dependencies...
    FP *feedparser.Client
}

// Index of stories
// GET /
func (c *Controller) Index(ctx context.Context) (stories *gofeed.Feed, err error) {

    return c.FP.FrontPage(ctx)

}
```

This is the original repository holding the hackernews client
https://github.com/matthewmueller/hackernews